# build haskell ghc from source on linux

Tags: linux, haskell, ghc

It seems there is a **circular dependency** when building ghc:

```
$ wget https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.2.2/ghc-9.2.2-src.tar.xz
$ tar -xf ghc-9.2.2-src.tar.xz
$ cd ghc-9.2.2/
$ sed -n "11,12p" INSTALL.md 
N.B. in particular you need GHC installed in order to build GHC,
because the compiler is itself written in Haskell.  For instructions
$ sudo apt install ghc # <----- somehow get an older version to build from source the new one
$ ./configure 
checking for gfind... no
checking for find... /usr/bin/find
checking for sort... /usr/bin/sort
checking for GHC Git commit id... given fbaee70d380973f71fa6e9e15be746532e5a4fc5
checking for ghc... /usr/bin/ghc
checking version of ghc... 8.6.5
configure: error: GHC version 8.10 or later is required to compile GHC. # ???!!!
```

So to build a new ghc, **some** older version of ghc is needed, but **not too old**.
The `apt-get` version **is** too old. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not a circular dependency, since the dependency is on an earlier version. I guess you will simply have to build intermediate versions of ghc first, i.e. version 8.10 and then 9.2. It is a common issue for compilers written in their own target language that they cannot be properly bootstrapped in a small number of stages.

Comment: so you suggest to build from source `8.10` then proeed to `9.2.2`?

Comment: I don't actually know much about ghc, so someone with expertise may have a better recommendation, but yes, that is what I would try. I just know that ghc is one of the compilers that linux distributions which value compilation and bootstrapping from source, e.g. gentoo and guix, have trouble with. As far as I know none of them currently manage to bootstrap it properly from source with a C compiler. They always package a compiled seed ghc.

Comment: For example, guix currently doesn't seem to have any ghc-9 version in its repository, but you can see [here](https://github.com/guix-mirror/guix/blob/master/gnu/packages/haskell.scm) that it compiles the following chain of versions of ghc to get to version 8.10: 7.8 -> 7.10 -> 8.0 -> 8.4 -> 8.6 -> 8.8 -> 8.10

Comment: If the goal is to get a working, modern GHC, then I strongly recommend simply downloading a binary. If the goal is to be able to modify GHC, then I strongly recommend downloading a binary, then using it to build GHC. Either way the first step is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Posting for self completeness according to the comment of @Daniel Wagner:

```
$ wget https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.2.2/ghc-9.2.2-x86_64-ubuntu20.04-linux.tar.xz
$ tar -xf ghc-9.2.2-x86_64-ubuntu20.04-linux.tar.xz
$ cd ghc-9.2.2/
$ ./configure # <----- you still have to do configre + make
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 9.2.2
```